# When sending an ajax get request to aws lambda through api gateway the headers are received with lowercase characters

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

When I request using fetch on node.js the header 'channelId' is received as 'channelId' but when I try to use a get request through jquery the header 'channelId' is received as 'channelid' and this makes things confusing. I set up the CORS to accept every type of header for testing. Why is this happening?